# Xcode 7.2.1. Your account already has has a valid destribution certificate and than an App Id is not available

Tags: ios, xcode, deployment, enterprise

I click to archive my app, then export, select save for Enterprise deployment, then I choose the Development Team.

Then appears this failure error:

[image]

I tried to fix it like the other similar questions but it does not fix.

What can I do??

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download `Distribution certificate` locally in your `keychain` and then `archive`.

Comment: I download the 'Distribution certificate' put in my keychain and archive but this it does not fix

Comment: Furthermore, in the keychain does not appear the private key, how can I fix this?

Comment: You have to install proper certificate for the distribution profile which you have downloaded from the provisioning profile portal.